# Graphisoft GDL - How to get layout name and number inside GDL object

Tags: gdl, archicad, graphisoft

I want to show the layout name and number inside a gdl object that I placed on my layout.

How can I get a layout name and number into my GDL script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the layout name in several ways inside your GDL script.

A commonly used solution is to use the autotext tags `<LAYOUTNAME>` or `<LAYOUTID>` as a string. This tag will be replaced by the layout name or layout id AFTER the gdl object has compiled.

```
xPos = 0;
yPos = 0;
TEXT2 xPos, yPos, '<LAYOUTNAME>'
```

or

```
TEXT2 xPos, yPos, '<LAYOUTID>'
```

All autotext tags can be found [here in the documentation](http://helpcenter.graphisoft.com/guides/archicad-18-int-reference-guide/documentation/annotation/autotext/autotext-reference-drawing/).

**Note:** Be aware that `<LAYOUTID>` and `<LAYOUTNUMBER>` are two different things!

The problem with this solution is that you cannot use the value in for example function to compare with a value. So this will never evaluate to true:

```
'<LAYOUTNAME>' = 'my layout name'
```

In case you want to do something like that that there is an alternative way using [the GDL `REQUEST` options function](http://gdl.graphisoft.com/gdl-docs/gdl-guide/chapter-12-miscellaneous/request-options/)

```
n = request ("HomeDB_info",  "", n, LayoutId, LayoutName, n)
```

The values will be stored in the variables `LayoutId` and `LayoutName`

This is also documented [here](http://www.graphisoft.com/ftp/techsupport/documentation/developer_docs/BasicLibraryDoc/15/DrawingTitle/DrawingTitle.html#title_GDLRequests) and mentioned [here on the ArchiCAD-TALK forum](http://archicad-talk.graphisoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=38528)

It is possible to evaluate this value and use this directly in your code:

```
IF LayoutName = 'my layout name' THEN
    ! layout name is 'my layout name'
ELSE
    ! layout name is something else
ENDIF
```